# swapping one library out for another

Tags: javascript, three.js

relatively simple task here but seeing as i'm just getting to grips with object oriented programming it is perplexing me. Im currently using the first function of [lon_lat_to_cartesian](https://gist.github.com/nicoptere/2f2571db4b454bb18cd9):

```
function lonLatToVector3( lng, lat, out )
{
out = out || new THREE.Vector3();

//flips the Y axis
lat = PI / 2 - lat;

//distribute to sphere
out.set(
            Math.sin( lat ) * Math.sin( lng ),
            Math.cos( lat ),
            Math.sin( lat ) * Math.cos( lng )
);

return out;

}
```

I call it within my glmain.js file using the following line:

```
position = lonLatToVector3(data.latitude, data.longitude);
```

(ie the latititude and longitude points given to it are turned into a vector)

I now wish to swap this library for [latlon-vectors.js](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/blob/master/latlon-vectors.js). Its the following lines(50-60) I want to use:

```
LatLon.prototype.toVector = function() {
var φ = this.lat.toRadians();
var λ = this.lon.toRadians();

// right-handed vector: x -> 0°E,0°N; y -> 90°E,0°N, z -> 90°N
var x = Math.cos(φ) * Math.cos(λ);
var y = Math.cos(φ) * Math.sin(λ);
var z = Math.sin(φ);

return new Vector3d(x, y, z);
};
```

to my limited newby knowledge this appears to be a method of the main object:

```
function LatLon(lat, lon) {
// allow instantiation without 'new'
if (!(this instanceof LatLon)) return new LatLon(lat, lon);

this.lat = Number(lat);
this.lon = Number(lon);
}
```

I'd have no problem calling this, i could just do:

```
position = LatLon(data.latitude, data.longitude);
```

but that would not accomplish my aim and convert my Lat, Lon points to a vector. how do I go on to call the aforementioned lines (50-60)?

Comment: I don't see why you cannot call `position = LatLon(data.latitude, data.longitude);` once you have included `latlon-vectors.js` in your project.

Comment: I had included it in my project, but couldn't get lines 50-60 to work aswell. Thanks to answer to my other recent post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001543/equate-the-length-of-a-vector-to-a-certain-value-in-three-js/30006913#30006913) I now have means to use this library.

Comment: looking at the code in latlon-vectors.js you need to call `position = LatLon(data.latitude, data.longitude); var vector = position.toVector();` to get the lat/lon into a vector.

Comment: yes thank you that worked, thats my answer(i'd be happy to tick it off if you post it as such) The only other thing i had to do was convert Vector3d into a new THREE.Vector3  so that I could work with it using three.js. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the code in latlon-vectors.js, in order to get the lat/lon into a vector you need to call:

```
var position = LatLon(data.latitude, data.longitude);
var vector = position.toVector();
```