# equate the length of a vector to a certain value in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been reading the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3.length) & [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js) to try and find out a way to compute the length of a vector and then set it to a defined value.

my code:

```
if (viewerPosition !== null && placementPosition !== null) {
    var vectorDiff = placementPosition.sub(viewerPosition);
    placementPosition.setY(0);
    placementPosition.multiplyScalar(100000);
    console.log(placementPosition)
```

the log returns:

```
Object { x: -23.658385352970377, y: 0, z: 9.121675219786463 }
```

Ive tried adding the line:

```
placementPosition.length (32);
```

to see if that would change the length of the vector to 32m, but unfortunately this did not work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// make the length of the vector 1.0
placementPosition.normalize();

// make the length of the vector 32
placementPosition.multiplyScalar(32);
```

Comment: Or use the method `Vector3.setLength( length );`

Comment: gaitat, that worked, and thanks for putting it in that format too, which explained it nicely. WestLangley, thanks for giving me an alternative version :)